# A complex SQL query requirement for a table containing data in unusual way

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I have a bit complex situation for extracting information from a table. I am not sure what is the best way to do it.

I have two tables :
student 
student_information

**student**

```
id          name
--          --------
1           shredder
2           Queen
```

**student_infromation**

```
student_id  property    value
----------  --------    -----
1           dept        CS
1           address     DE
1           class       X
2           dept        MS
2           address     DE
2           class       IX
```

Running:

```
select * from student
join student_information si on student.id = si.student_id
```

Gives me output like this :

```
id          name        student_id  property    value
--          --------    ----------  --------    -----
1           shredder        1       dept        CS
1           shredder        1       address     DE
1           shredder        1       class       X
2           queen           2       dept        MS
2           queen           2       address     DE
2           queen           2       class       IX



select * from student
join student_information si on student.id = si.student_id
where property in ('dept','class')
```

*I need information just for Dept and Class for each student,but currently the property class and department is listed as row. I want to make column out of it.*

Can we construct the table like this?

```
id          name        dept        class
--          --------    ----------  ------
1           shredder    cS          X       
1           queen       MS          IX
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Comment: sure @philipxy got it

Comment: Text-only is good. Now: What's your question? Your problem? What's the last query? If it's wrong, what's the 1st expression that returns what you don't expect & what do you expect & why? Why is that last table there? This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. How is your desired result a function of input? When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. We still can't cut & paste & run an example.

Comment: @philipxy thanks, I will modify it to make it more friendly

Comment: Your edit didn't address my last comment. PS Earlier I removed those fonts that you put back since they added nothing & still don't. Fonts do not bring clarity. Clarity brings clarity. But given the example we can guess what you might want. It is a "pivot" & it s a faq many, many times over. But if you don't write a clear sentence saying what you want, you can't search for it. Please before considering posting google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may join the two tables and then aggregate by student, turning out the properties you want using pivoting logic:

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN si.property = 'dept'  THEN si.value END) AS dept,
    MAX(CASE WHEN si.property = 'class' THEN si.value END) AS class
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN student_information si
    ON s.id = si.student_id
GROUP BY
    s.id,
    s.name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Great,acutally I need this for Spark DataFrame Transformation. This idea helps.Thanks Man!!!

Comment: If you need help with Spark, then you should add the appropriate tag(s).  You tagged MySQL, so this is the code I have given you.

Comment: your sql plan helped me solve my Spark Transformation :)

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't get the joke, but when I looked up that clip I was shocked to see Donald Sutherland so young.  And now I know something about your age (40+).

Comment: OK, I feel like Madame Butterfly meeting the American Consul